# How to make project tango delta camera camera to VR mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, virtual-reality

According to project tango tutorial

> Once you're set up, try making a simple VR application on Project
>   Tango using our Unity prefab motion tracking tutorial. Also check out
>   our Unity code samples on GitHub for more inspiration!

https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/

but the prefab motion tracking tutorial don't have any VR instruction

https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-prefab-motion-tracking

Anyone know how to make the delta camera camera to VR mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it under tango VR examples

https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity